# Вывести количество файлов в директории, не используя конвейеры и tree

Tags: linux, bash

Вопрос из лабы по ОС. Делал `ls / | wc -l` - c pipe. И `tree -L 1 /` без pipe.
Преподаватель сказал, что надо без `tree`, и использовать команды, которые учили в 1й лабе. Команды 1й лабы: `man`, `passwd`, `date`, `cat`, `more`, `wc`, `who`, `ls`, `cd`, `cal`, `cp`, `mv`, `mkdir`, `rm`, `rmdir`. Как это сделать — идей нет.

Comment: С 2008-го года на линуксе, тоже интересно как это сделать без пайпов.

Comment: Подсказка: для этого не нужны никакие из перечисленных команд.

Comment: `>` и `<<` можно?

Comment: @user7860670, а как, если `использовать команды которые учили в 1й лабе`?

Comment: `ls | wc -l` — нормальный христоматйный вариант… так что ответ, скорей всего, будет каким-то дурацким или тем же самым… из альтернатив я могу предложить только какой-нить извращённый bash'изм вроде `(a=(*); cat <<<"${#a[@]}")`...